# how to print lines matching between two patterns but second pattern existing multiple times in a file using sed command or awk command?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have this input file F1 :

```
Good morning!
Have a nice day;
see you again the next day;
Bye;
```

I want to print the lines between "Have" and "day".
I tried with this command:`*sed -n '/Have/,/day/ p*' F1`
 output is: Have a nice day
But I want second line also to be printed as it also has the same pattern "day".
Desired output:
*Have a nice day;
see you again the next day;*

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multiple-Line.html). Can it be of some help? If yes, I can format a pretty answer.

Comment: `sed '/Have/,/day/!d' file` or `sed -n '/Have/,/day/p' file` already has the desired output. The `/.../,/.../` toggles over 2 or more line it will not toggle on a single line.

Comment: Your requirements aren't clear at all. Do you want to print from the first `Have` in the file to the last `day` or from the first Have to the first day thats not on the same line or from the last Have to the first day after it or something else? Do you want to print every occurence of this range in the file or only the first or only the last or something else? What should happen if they're nested? [edit] your question to clearly state your requirements and come up with a MUCH better sample input and provide the associated expected output if you'd like help with your real problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed  '/Have/{:a;x;s/^\(.*\n.*day[^\n]*\).*/\1/p;x;h;d};H;$!d;ba' file
```

The command `/Have/,/day/` collects the shortest number of lines between `Have` and `day`, is what you require the longest? If so here is such a solution.

Store lines in the hold space which contain `Have` in the first line, then at each occurrence of the the word `Have` delete lines following the last `day` of the previous collection and print them. At end-of-file repeat this one further time.

N.B. The command `/Have/,/day/` will collect all lines from the first containing `Have` to the end-of-file if no line containing `day` is encountered. The above solution prints only when both conditions are met.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in `awk`. Basically, it makes 2 passes - which is why `F1` appears twice at the end of the command as a file to process.

On the first pass (FNR==NR), it saves the line number in `s` (start) of the first occurrence of "Have", and it saves the line number of the last occurrence in `e` (end) of the word "day".

On the second pass, (FNR!=NR), it prints lines between `s` and `e` (start and end).

```
awk '/Have/&&s==0{s=FNR} /day/&&FNR==NR{e=NR} (FNR!=NR)&&(FNR>=s)&&(FNR<=e)' F1 F1
```

Answer (score 0):

The following would do it one-way

```
awk '/Have/           { p=1 }
     /day/  && (p==1) { p=2; print; next }
     !/day/ && (p==2) { p = 0 }
     p' <file>
```

What we do here is to keep track of a label `p`. If `Have` is found, set `p=1`, if `day` is found, set `p=2`, also print and move to the next line. If `p>1` it means we found a `day`, if that line does not contain `day` set the print-label back to zero, otherwise print.

The output is

```
Have a nice day;
see you again the next day;
```

This will print blocks and not until the last `day`.

An input of the form

```
Good morning!
Have a nice day;
see you again the next day;
Bye;

Good morning!
Have a nice day;
see you again the next day;
Bye;
```

will output:

```
Have a nice day;
see you again the next day;
Have a nice day;
see you again the next day;
```